# Quality of different target Surface types in Camera 2 API

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview, android-camera2

Using Camera2 API you can specify one or more target surfaces such as a preview surface (`SurfaceTexture`, `SurfaceView`), a recording surface (from `MediaRecorder#getSurface`  or `MediaCodec#createInputSurface`) or a processing one such as `Allocation`.

Is there any difference in quality of the frames delivered to each surface type? For example a `SurfaceTexture` is mostly mentioned as a preview surface in the documentation but it can also be used for processing using OpenGL. Is there any drawback in using it instead of using an Allocation and process it in RenderScript?

Is video stabilization applied in `SurfaceTexture` frames?